# Round photos with outline-offset on mobile devices

Tags: css, outline, border-radius

I'm stumped and need some help. I have CSS written to make photos round with a thin 1px outline set to offset -12px and appear inside the photo. This works fine for desktop devices, but the outline radius does not carry over the border-radius: 50% on mobile devices. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how to fix.

```css
.round-photo {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  margin: auto;
}
.round-photo img {
  width:100%;
  height:inherit;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  outline: solid 1px white;
  outline-offset: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-photo">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people">
</div>
```

[Here is what I am trying to get my photos to look like when viewing on mobile devices. Where the outline-offset appears inside the image and retains the 50% radius - forming a complete circle inside the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv9zY.jpg)

[However this is what my image looks like in Brave/Chrome on an Apple iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rQeO.jpg)

[And this is what my image looks like in Duck Duck Go on an Apple iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVfgV.jpg)

[And here is what my image looks like in Safari on an Apple iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sasvv.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of how your code looks on your mobile device. Include the exact model and the exact browser your are using. Also check other models with their browsers and add screenshots from these models as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Have created a codepen. let me know if this works for you ?

https://codepen.io/_makki/pen/JjOYJgL

```
.round-photo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.round-photo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid white;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.round-photo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prograk, your solution was very helpful and worked like a charm. Many thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome bro. Thank you too.